# Android - Chrome special characters color

Tags: android, css

Is there any way to change color for special characters on Android ?
For example this:

```
<span id='tm'>&#8482;</span> // trade sign
```

is always blue. I try to change it in every way by CSS and JS after page load but nothing works.

Comment: Have you tried `#tm{ color: #hex value goes here}` or inline style `<span style="color: #hex value goes here">&#8482;</span>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48153836/2943533
The solution mentioned would work for this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm under-thinking this but a simple `css` style should do the trick.

**Option 1: HTML-code**

```
<span id='tm'>&#8482;</span>

#tm {
  color: red;
}
```

**Option 2: Entity**

```
<span id='tm'>&trade;</span>

#tm {
  color: red;
}
```

**Option 3: Unicode** place `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the `<head>` (HTML5).

```
<span id='tm'></span>

#tm:before {
  content:'\2122';
  color: red;
}
```

This works fine on with my LG-G2 Android phone. [Desktop](http://jsfiddle.net/clarketm/rd5xzobx/) | [Mobile](https://jsfiddle.net/clarketm/rd5xzobx/embedded/result/)

Comment: really You think that saying "every way by CSS"  i do not try this? :)

Comment: @Michael: This will work.  If it doesn't work for you, something else is wrong.  And we really can't make assumptions about what you tried unless you actually show us.

Comment: @Michael - do you have `<meta charset="UTF-8">` (HTML5) in your `<head>`?