# Changing font color of HTML Symbol

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

i am having an issue when changing the color of a HTML Symbol, what i have is this

```html
<span style="color: rgb(42, 170, 82);">&#9899;</span>
```

and for some odd reason on some google chrome did not change the font color (works fine on IE, FF and most of GC), if anyone know something about this issue please enlighten me. Thanks

Comment: is it an emoji?

Comment: if its an emoji, then it might not color it, but use the built-in gliphs

Comment: it's and HTML Symbol, just a circle, let me edit my post

Comment: seems like a chrome bug.

Comment: Is it specific versions of Chrome it doesn't work with? Given it works on some Chrome browsers, I'd agree that it sounds like a bug in certain versions.

Comment: well I'm running Chrome and I see it just fine (a green circle). Are you sure there are no CSS rules with more specificity or something?

Comment: Well it is explicitly the (medium) _black_ circle Unicode character ... https://emojipedia.org/medium-black-circle/, so ...

Comment: yeah on my chrome it works fine and on some others it doesnt, the most probably problem is a version issue but i wanted to know if someone know the exact problem,

Comment: Works on firefox, does not work on Chrome and Safari  (All on Mac OS High Sierra

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**FIX:**

```html
<span style="color: rgb(42, 170, 82);">&#9899;</span>

<span style="color: transparent;  text-shadow: 0 0 0 green; ">&#9899;</span>

<span style="color: transparent;  text-shadow: 0 0 0 rgb(42, 170, 82); ">&#9899;</span>
```

This works for Chrome hope it helps you bro.

Comment: This seems to work when checked in a html online editor but when using this same <span> code in a html <table> and post the data on confluence using confluence REST API it doesn't change color of this circle geometric html symbol. Is it because of the css-property text-shadow?

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be an issue with Chrome, but you can workaround it using `text-shadow`...

```css
span {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 rgb(0, 128, 0);
}
```

```html
<span>&#9899;</span>
```