# How to change HTML symbol's colour?

Tags: html, css

im using telephone's symbol , the first symbol (&#9742) turns into colorful and (&#9743) turns into blue colour , in w3school both should be black and white

i tried to using symbol without html code (just copy and paste from other site) and its also turns to blue

```html
<div id="navigation">
    <ul style="justify-content: space-around;">
        <li><a href="#">&#9742 085881533938</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

i want to have black and white symbol

Comment: #navigation ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navigation ul li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}

#navigation li:not(:first-child):before {
    content: " | ";
}

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152562/changing-font-color-of-html-symbol

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<div id="navigation">
<ul style="justify-content: space-around;">
    <li><a href="#"><span style="color: #808080">&#9742</span> 085881533938</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer ! unfortunately the symbol still colorful

Comment: @AndreasS did you check the link that Dadboz sent in your question? Are you using Chrome? This may be a Chrome issue

Comment: It is set to gray. anyways You can choose a color code from here  https://htmlcolorcodes.com/  and just replace my color code in the span

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
#navigation ul li span{
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul style="justify-content: space-around;">
            <li><a href="#"><span>&#9742</span> 085881533938</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```